# Write <?xml?> in PHP file

Tags: php, html, xml, xhtml

I have a `index.php` file:

```
<?php
// Load resources shared across the website
include '../path/to/other_file.php';
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xml:lang="es" lang="es" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head prefix="article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Code -->

</body>
</html>
```

When I load it, it shows nothing. I used [this online tool](http://www.meandeviation.com/tutorials/learnphp/php-syntax-check/v5-3/syntax-check.php) to see what's happening. The problem occurs at line 5.

Probably it's that I'm using `<?` to introduce the XHTML document, but I guess PHP thinks the following word would be `php` (`<?php //CODE ?>`) instead of `xml` (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`)

How can I fix it? I think it's called "parsing" or "espacing" the characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because PHP thinks you're trying to enter "PHP mode" when you're doing `<?`, when in fact you're trying to access XML. The simple solution to this is to disable what's called "PHP short tags", where PHP recognizes `<?` as a valid opening-tag.

You can do this by various methods, all which effectively do the same

1. Add `short_open_tag=Off` in your `php.ini`
2. <strike>Add `ini_set('short_open_tag', '0');` at the top of your specified file</strike>
3. In `php_value short_open_tag 0` in your `.htaccess`
4. Use `<?php echo "<?xml ... ?>";` to add your XML.

Comment: Not 2 - `short_open_tag` is `PHP_INI_PERDIR` and can't
be changed with `ini_set()`: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: Really, @AbraCadaver? TIL! I'll strike over it!

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this problem using a simple echo :

```
include '../path/to/other_file.php';
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the browser, that the php file is an xml file with this line:

`header("Content-type: text/xml");`

put this right after you start the php tag, so script can override the header

Comment: The problem is happening on the server, because PHP doesn't understand `<?xml` in a PHP script.

Comment: While sending a MIME type header is certainly necessary for an XHTML file (otherwise the browser will think it's an HTML file), this is the the problem the OP is asking about. By the way, `application/xhtml+xml` is the preferred one, although `text/xml` will work just fine.